# python - can't come back when reaching EOF when using less as a pager

Tags: python, subprocess, less

I am using `less` as a pager so that output of the application can be read easily. I create the subprocess like this:

```
a_process = subprocess.Popen(["less"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then I write into the pager like this (multiple lines):

```
a_process.stdin.write("hello\n".encode())
a_process.stdin.flush()
```

Before I finish execution I call `a_process.wait()` and the user is able to move up and down as expected.... if the user hits `q` the pager ends and the python application ends as there is no more stuff in the python script....  *however*, if the user reaches the end of the output I provided to `less`, the UI freezes.... the user can't go up, can't quit using `q`... only `ctrl-c` will work to finish execution.

What piece am I missing to avoid reaching this state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`less` doesn't know that it has reached EOF, it's waiting for more output that fills up the next page.

To tell it that the output is done, close the pipe:

```
close(a_process.stdin)
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Let me give it a try.